# Fallo con Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

Tengo una base de datos con los productos disponibles. Se facilita un formulario a los trabajadores para que pidan los productos que necesitan. Quiero conseguir que salga algún mensaje cuando pidan un artículo que no está disponible o si piden más de lo que hay.

> Tengo estas tablas:
>
> **Material:** ID, Articulo, Descripcion, Stock, Ubicacion
>
> **Pedidos:** IdPedido, IDArticulo, Articulo, Asignado a, Cantidad,Prestado(Si/No), Definitivo(Si/No), Fecha
>
> **Personal**: Código, Nombre, Apellido 1, Apellido 2.
>
> Consultas:
>
> **Existencias:** Muestra el stock actual disponible. (IDArticulo (Pedidos), Articulo (Material), Descripcion (Material), Stock (Material), Stock_Restante `(Stock_Restante:
>   SiInm(EsNulo([Material]![Stock]-[Total_Pedidos]![SumaDeCantidad]);[Material]![Stock];[Material]![Stock]-[Total_Pedidos]![SumaDeCantidad]))`
>
> **Relaciones:** Total_Pedidos (Articulo) - Material (ID), Material (ID) - Pedidos (IDArticulo)
>
> **Solicitar_Material:** Muestra el stock que ha sido pedido. (Asignado a, Articulo, Cantidad, Prestado, Definitivo, Fecha)
>
> **Relaciones:** Ninguna
>
> **Total_Pedidos:** Calcula el Stock total (Articulo (Pedidos), Cantidad (Pedidos) - Total: Suma)
>
> **Relaciones:** ID (Material) - IDArticulo (Pedidos)
>
> Formularios:
>
> **Material:** Formulario que usará el admin para añadir un producto. (ID, Articulo, Descripcion, Cantidad, Ubicacion)
>
> **Pedidos:** Formulario que usará el empleado para pedir un producto. (IDPedido, ID (Material), Articulo, Descripcion, Asignado a, Cantidad,
>   Prestado, Definitivo, Fecha)
>
> **Relaciones de tablas:** Material [ID] - Pedidos [IDArticulo], dbo_Personal [Nombre] - Pedidos [Asignado a]

Tengo la regla de validación `(>=0)` insertada en [*Stock*], [*Cantidad*] y en el formulario [*Pedidos*] en el campo [*Cantidad*] para que no se inserten valores negativos en el propio campo.

El problema es cuando alguien desde el formulario pide más material del que hay disponible. El valor (mostrado en *Existencias*) se vuelve negativo, y eso es lo que quiero evitar, haciendo que salga un mensaje estilo *"No queda más del producto seleccionado"*.

Tengo este código en un evento "*Antes de Actualizar*" en el campo *Cantidad* del formulario.

```
Private Sub Cantidad_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
If Me.Cantidad > DLookup("Stock_Restante", "Existencias", "IDArticulo =" & Me.IDArticulo) Then
   MsgBox "No hay suficiente stock del producto para esa salida", vbInformation, "REVISA"
   Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

Pero cuando intento insertar un nuevo registro, o incluso editar uno ya existente, me sale el mensaje de error del código "***No hay suficiente stock del producto para esa salida***", inserte cualquier cantidad, quede o no stock en ese artículo, sigue saliendo ese mensaje.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Arreglado!
El campo [Cantidad] lo tenía con tipo texto en vez de con tipo Número, lo cambié y ya va bien. Fallo tonto por mi parte, pero me daba mucha tralla. Dejo el código con el que me funcionó.

```
Private Sub Cantidad_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
If Me.Cantidad > DLookup("Stock_Restante", "Existencias", "IDArticulo =" & Me.IDArticulo) Then
   MsgBox "No hay suficiente stock del producto para esa salida", vbInformation, "REVISA"
   Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema esta en esta linea

```
If Me.Cantidad > DLookup("Stock_Restante", "Existencias", "IDArticulo =" & Me.IDArticulo)
```

No tengo la certeza de como se manejan los valores en el lenguaje en el que estas trabajando, pero en la mayoría se debe cumplir que Me.Cantidad > Numero, con lo cual el compilador puede arrojarte un resultado de dicha operación ojo que los datos deben ser numéricos no sirve si un dato es un numero pero viene formateado como string, podría también afectar a la operación, podrías enviar dentro del mensaje una respuesta de Me.Cantidad para ver que esta arrojando y DLookup para ver que esta arrojando también, esto te dará luces de que es lo que sucede.

saludos.